# Destroy database session when user leaves website

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2 and recently changed my session handler to database.
Everything seems to be working fine, except when a user leaves the website without logging out the session is left active.

In my core.php file I have configured database session handler as follows:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database'
));
```

How do I configure cakephp database sessions to destroy the session when a user leaves the site without logging out?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. PHP runs on-demand and can't possibly know when a user stops browsing the site. You basically have 2 options:

1. Write a script to check your session store to find sessions that haven't been accessed in X seconds, and clear them out. Call this script with a cron job.
2. Check the session when the user comes back, and clear out any stale data. You'll still need to do some cleanup from time to time to get rid of session data from users that *never* come back.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers. This kind of sucks because having database sessions has some benefits

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are stored on the server, so if the browser is closed or the user goes to a different page, there is no obligation that it informs the server about this action.

Session are stored for a certain time in the server, and after some time of inactivity, it will be destroyed there automatically.

Check Sessions info in [CakePHP cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) for more details

Comment: You can use HTML5's local storage database feature.

Comment: @ColeJohnson you mean to handle cakephp session? Even though, that will depend on browser support of the feature, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution that will work in some cases but probably isn't a great solution:

```
<body onUnload="ajaxFunctionToDeleteSession();">
 some random stuff goes here
</body>
```

So `ajaxFunctionToDeleteSession` would call via Ajax a url that would delete the session.

A few problems with this that I see:

1. Called anytime someone closes an open page of your site. Which means if someone opens up multiple windows of your site closes one, their entire session, including for the other open tabs is closed
2. There are probably cases in which someone goes to your site, does something accidentally closes the open window, reopens the site and things will look different because the session is gone.

But if you absolutely must delete a session when someone leaves the site, this may give a way to start approaching the problem.

Comment: onUnload is called also when you navigate to a different page, even if you are still logged in the application, so this will kill the session when you don't want it to happen...